# Serialization and Deserialization Issue in Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis, deserialization

I have two modules in Spring Boot Microservices `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`. Both modules share a common POJO class called `CacheData`, whose object is stored in Redis.

`ModuleA` puts  the data in redis using

```
private final ValueOperations<String, CachedData>keyToValueOperations;
```

like:

```
   CacheData toSet = new CacheData("abc","utc",Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
   keyToValueOperations.set('key', toSet);
```

```
public class CacheData implements Serializable {
  @Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = -5640664404726218923L;
  private String id;
  private String timeZone;
  private List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

  public CacheData() {}

  public CacheData(String id, String timeZone, List<Integer> intList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.timeZone = timeZone;
    this.intList.addAll(intList);
  }


  public List<Integer> getIntList() {
    return intList;
  }

 
  public CacheData setIntList(List<Integer> intList) {
    this.intList.clear();
    if (intList != null) {
      this.intList.addAll(intList);
    }
    return this;
  }

 
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

 
  public CacheData setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  public String getTimeZone() {
    return timeZone;
  }

  
  public CacheData setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
    this.timeZone = timeZone;
    return this;
  }
}
```

But when I try to get the same data from `ModuleB` like:

```
   CacheData toGet = keyToValueOperations.get('key);
```

I am getting error as:

```
    java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:112) ~[snappy-java-1.1.9.1.jar:1.1.9.1]
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method) ~[snappy-java-1.1.9.1.jar:1.1.9.1]
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawUncompress(Snappy.java:480) ~[snappy-java-1.1.9.1.jar:1.1.9.1]
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:519) ~[snappy-java-1.1.9.1.jar:1.1.9.1]
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:494) ~[snappy-java-1.1.9.1.jar:1.1.9.1]
    at com.qfree.auth.service.SnappyRedisSerializer.deserialize(SnappyRedisSerializer.java:59) ~[auth-util-test.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeValue(AbstractOperations.java:360) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations$ValueDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(AbstractOperations.java:62) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:224) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:191) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:97) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.get(DefaultValueOperations.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
```

I am using same serializer for both modules defined as the `@Bean` of respective modules as:

```
   @Bean
   public ValueOperations<String, CachedData> keyToValueOperations(
   RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
   RedisTemplate<String, CachedData> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
   SnappyRedisSerializer<String> snappyRedisSerializer =
     new SnappyRedisSerializer<>(new FstRedisSerializer<>(), RedisSerializer.java());
   template.setKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
   template.setHashKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
   template.setValueSerializer(snappyRedisSerializer);
   template.setHashValueSerializer(snappyRedisSerializer);
   template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
   template.afterPropertiesSet();
   return template.opsForValue();
   }
```

Related codes are:

```
 public class SnappyRedisSerializer<T> implements RedisSerializer<T> {
     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SnappyRedisSerializer.class);
 private final RedisSerializer<T> innerSerializer;
 private final RedisSerializer<?> legacySerializer;


 public SnappyRedisSerializer(
     RedisSerializer<T> innerSerializer, RedisSerializer<?> legacySerializer) {
   this.innerSerializer = innerSerializer;
   this.legacySerializer = legacySerializer;
 }


 public SnappyRedisSerializer(RedisSerializer<T> innerSerializer) {
   this.innerSerializer = innerSerializer;
   this.legacySerializer = null;
 }

 
 @Override
 public byte[] serialize(T object) throws SerializationException {
   try {
     byte[] bytes = innerSerializer.serialize(object);
     return Snappy.compress(bytes);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new SerializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
   }
 }


 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public T deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
   try {
     if (bytes == null) {
       return null;
     }
     byte[] bos = Snappy.uncompress(bytes);
     return innerSerializer.deserialize(bos);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     LOGGER.warn("Could not deserialize object, falling back to legacy", e);
     if (legacySerializer == null) {
       throw new SerializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
     }
     return (T) legacySerializer.deserialize(bytes);
   }
 }
}
```

```
public class FstRedisSerializer<T> implements RedisSerializer<T> {

  static ThreadLocal<FSTConfiguration> conf =
      ThreadLocal.withInitial(FSTConfiguration::createDefaultConfiguration);


  @Override
  public byte[] serialize(T t) throws SerializationException {
    FSTConfiguration fst = conf.get();
    return fst.asByteArray(t);
  }

 
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public T deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
    FSTConfiguration fst = conf.get();
    return (T) fst.asObject(bytes);
  }
}
```

Note: From `ModuleA` , I can get the data using

```
CacheData toGet = keyToValueOperations.get('key);
```

Any help?